# How do I output a string or number in JavaScript using format specifier?

Tags: javascript

```js
var b=4; //variable
document.write("The value  of b is %d", b);
```

In Java, it would be:

```java
int b;`
System.out.printf("the value of b is %d", b);
```

Comment: `console.log` instead of `document.write`? [console: Using string substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console#Using_string_substitutions)

Comment: There are a variety of ways to do this i'm sure, but my preferred way is Template Literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: what do you mean (exactly) by ""format specifier" for JavaScript?

Comment: see if this gives you enough information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43660720/125981

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript equivalent to printf/String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: You can use C-like string formatting as in your example. The problem is you need `console.log` rather than `document.write`. Change that and it will work! It's not a very common way of manipulating strings in JavaScript though. Here's some more info https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/14972/formatting-console-output

Comment: Thank you all, but it seems I haven't gotten exactly what I want. I will keep on studying.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
let b = 4;

let valueString = `The value of B is: ${b}`
```

Comment: @davejimm or you use just simple concatenation:  `'the value of b is '+b`

Comment: but for multiple values, mixed with strings, that is way more efficient.. also @dave, the specific back quotes ONLY use that `${}` syntax

Comment: I already know this; I was looking for another way. Appreciated, man.